# Formula field with BR() function in lightning calendar

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, calendar

I created a formula field to show two field values but in separate line. Here is the formula field with BR() function `Field1& BR() & Field2`.
I created a calendar for a user and It is coming in calendar like `Field1<br>Field2` instead of coming in separate line. Could anyone tell me please that is there anything I am doing wrong or it is a known issue for salesforce?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You can try this method, though it looks pretty messy: https://automationchampion.com/2015/08/06/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-40-adding-a-line-break-in-process-builder-formula/

From what I've found, there doesn't seem to be a way to show unescaped HTML in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to get around the limitation with calendars in Lightning Experience where only one field can be selected as the `Field Name to Display`.

As you've already discovered, you can combine fields in a formula field.  But the way Salesforce built its Calendar product, it looks like any line breaks will be stripped out of event names, regardless of how they're implemented.  That's true if the line break is implemented in a formula field via `BR()`, or even if you use a Text Area field and create a line break using the `Enter` key.

Here's a text area field I created:

[image: a basic text area field]

When I try to use this field as the Field Name to Display, I get this:

[image: a calendar event with text area field as display name]

So I'm afraid you're out of luck when it comes to breaking lines in calendar event display names.  Maybe consider using a symbol separator, e.g. |, *, -, etc?